# Smoke domain casts shadow despite the 'shadow' option is disabled in Ray Visibility

Tags: smoke-simulation, shadows

There is a point light just about the center of the smoke domain and even though the shadow ray visibility is disabled I keep getting flickering shadow glitches on the rendered animation. No flickering when I do not render the smoke domain.

I tried increasing the max bounces for transparency or repositioning the light but to no avail. The only workaround I found is to disable the cast shadow option for the point light and limit the ray length so it doesn't light up the whole scene. It worked but now I no longer have the good looking casted shadows on the character so it's not the exact desired result.

WDYT? Is this some type of a bug or there is an actual workaround for this issue?
Tried on 3.3 and 3.5

[image: preview]